# How to calculate the average Score for only a particular student node, instead of the average of all scores

Tags: c#

I have an XML file of students and their scores. Here is an example of one student node. I have other students following.

```
<Students>
  <Student>
    <Name> Billy Blue </Name>
    <Grade> 1 </Grade>
    <Sex> Male </Sex>
    <Age> 7 </Age>
    <Picture> c:/School/Students/BillyBlue </Picture>
    <Grades>
      <Score>80.5</Score>
      <Score>100.0</Score>
      <Score>70.0</Score>
      <Score>0.0</Score>
      <Score>0.0</Score>
      <Score>0.0</Score>
      <Score>0.0</Score>
      <Score>0.0</Score>
      <Score>0.0</Score>
      <Score>0.0</Score>
    </Grades>
  </Student>
```

I want to print out the average of their scores for each student.  My code is currently printing the average of all scores in the file.

```
     foreach (XElement student in listStudents)
        {
           IEnumerable<XElement> listScores =
                from XElement in listStudents.Descendants("Grades").Elements("Score")
                .Where(x => Convert.ToSingle(x.Value) != 0.0)
                select XElement;

            var fAverageScore = 0.0;
            foreach (XElement score in listScores)
            {
                fAverageScore += Convert.ToSingle(score.Value);

            }

            Console.WriteLine("Average Score: " + (fAverageScore / listScores.Count()).ToString("0.00"));
            Console.WriteLine("\n");
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to change the following :

```
listStudents.Descendants("Grades").Elements("Score")
```

to use:

```
student.Elements("Grades").Elements("Score")
```

so that it only reads from that particular student node not all the students.

You can call the [`Elements`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.linq.xelement?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2) method to get the children element `Grades` of the `Student` and then get each score.

It would be something like:

```
from XElement in student.Elements("Grades").Elements("Score")
```